# Front-to-Back Analogue for "Lateral"

Tags: single-word-requests

If "lateral" can be phrased as "side-to-side", what would be the adjective for "front-to-back"?

For example, in a car, you feel *lateral* acceleration in a sharp turn, and _______ acceleration when hitting the brakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm used to hearing it referred to as *longitudinal* in reference to things like acceleration.

> Longitudinal acceleration refers to acceleration in a straight line, with a positive value to indicate what we normally call acceleration and a negative value for braking. Lateral acceleration is an effective measure of cornering performance and what automotive people test on a skidpad.

From [Inside Motorcycles](http://www.insidemotorcycles.com/component/k2/item/229-analyzing-gps-data-lateral-and-longitudinal-acceleration.html)

Answer (score 0):

In anatomy this is referred to as anterior-posterior.